# Set selected color of cell in UiCollectionView in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using collectionview to display data.

each cell's selected and unselected color is there

but i want to set default color of first cell in collectionview.

[image]

if there are 10 data. my first cell should be like in screenshot

how to achieve this?
when i set color at indexpath this issue occurs

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For **two different colors based on selected state of the cell**, you may need to **subclass** your UICollectionViewCell like this:

```
import UIKit 

class YourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! // for example - some UI element inside cell ...

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.yellow
            self.imageView.alpha = isSelected ? 0.75 : 1.0
        }  
      }
    }


// and below you will have your original code

class YourViewController: UICollectionViewController {

... etc
```

Answering your question - for **exceptional style of the first cell**:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell ... 

        if(indexPath.row == 0) { //for first cell in the collection
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
```

Comment: what to do by default color should be black at first index

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Change colors as you need

Comment: Yes, because my code is just an example, written in Swift 3.0, so if you write in Swift 2, just follow the idea and you get that code run... The idea is to subclass collectionView cell.

Comment: where to call this method

Comment: The method is called via UICollectionViewCell delegate, so you don't have to call it anywhere. It handles it automatically.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.will let you know if any issues

Comment: what to do at didselectatindexpath?

Comment: A delegate method `didSelectItemAt indexPath` is used for example for going to the next controller or for action with your collection. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview?language=objc

Comment: exactly i want to ask that this method need to call at didselect?

Comment: No, you don't have to call it anywhere. iOS SDK handles it for you. So the code I put in my answer - JUST INSERT to your swift file in top of it, above all the code. That's it.

Comment: If possible, make another question. Or is it easy to help you here?

Comment: suppose there is 8 items in collectionview.first index should be of red color.other will change according to selection

Comment: Please Check my Updated Question.This issue i am facing when i tried your code.two index color are same

Comment: @KrutarthPatel I updated my answer again :) Please check cellForRow method first. What do you have in your numberOfRows delegate method?

Comment: i am still left with this issus

Comment: @KrutarthPatel please post full code of class you work in. It is hard to understand your sentences and issue as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327000/in-collectionview-how-to-set-colors-according-to-selection

Comment: You can add this code if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.isSelected = true
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
        } when you have a issue select and deselect the same colour

Comment: iOS 15 update: if you try to set the `cell.isSelected = true` manually the OS resets it back at some point. Worked in iOS 14.

Answer (score 10):

this is my code for this issue. Hope it save time for you :)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    
    if let indexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems, let indexP = indexPaths.first {
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = indexP == indexPath ? .white : .lightGray
    }
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = .white 
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {
        return
    }
    
    cell.bgView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
}
```

Answer (score 2):

call selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: method after reloadData method of UICollectionView

e.g.

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView()
collectionView.reloadData()     
collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
```

Comment: Solution is perfect
just missed where to post this

Answer (score 1):

Per to @pedroun's answer, here is my updated answer to make your first cell's default color. Hope this helps you.

```
@IBOutlet weak var cellImageview: UIImageView!

var cellIndex: Int? {
    didSet {
        guard let index = cellIndex else { return }
        if index != 0 {
            contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()//change this to your unselected cell color.
        }else{
            contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()//this is default color for your first cell.
            cellImageview.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}

override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.redColor(): UIColor.blueColor()//change colors as per your requirements
        cellImageview.alpha = selected ? 0.75 : 1.0
    }
}
```

For the `cellIndex` property, you need to set it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as `cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row`

Comment: Ok i will check and will let you know.thank you for response

Comment: Issue at indexpath.first cell is selected but when i select other indexpath both are selected

Answer (score 0):

There is two delegate method in UICollectionViewDelegate.

didDeselectItemAtIndexPath & didSelectItemAtIndexPath

when you click collection cell, you can get indexPath of the cell. And you can get collection cell by using cellForItemAtIndexPath

I have experienced in UITableView and I think UICollectionView is same with following logic.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row < arrData.count && arrData.count > 0{
        if let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? GARatesCell {
        selectedCell.viewBG.backgroundColor = COLOR_NAV_BAR
        selectedCell.lblTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        btnShare.backgroundColor = COLOR_NAV_BAR
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if  indexPath.row < arrData.count && arrData.count > 0{
        let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? GARatesCell
        if deselectedCell != nil {
            deselectedCell?.viewBG.backgroundColor =  COLOR_BG_BAR
            deselectedCell?.lblTitle.textColor = COLOR_NAV_BAR
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok.But at first index i want to set color
than after color will change in deselect and didselect methods
i am changing colors at this methods
but at first index it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a perfect solution. But it's works.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    collectionView.visibleCells.forEach {
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to Add the below line in the `view controller` when cell loads(i.e. add it in `didLoad` or `willAppear`).

```
self.DateCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
```

Then in UICollectionViewCell class add below method:

```
class DateCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var dateLable: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
    }
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet{
            if self.isSelected {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6FD5C9")
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FFFFFF")
            }
        }
    }
}
```