# in Collectionview how to set colors according to selection?

Tags: ios, swift, collections

My requirement is to set by default color at first `indexPath` and I want to change colors according to selection.

My Requirement is when collectionview will load at first index background color should be Red Color.and deselected color is blue color.
how to manage this
Here is my code

```
import UIKit
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.redColor(): UIColor.blueColor()
    }
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var collView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    if(indexPath.row == 0) { //for first cell in the collection
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    return cell
}

}
```

by this code my output is

[image: Issue]

Issue is when I click on first `indexPath` it works but by selecting others my two colors are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` reload the `collectionView` and after that explicitly select the first cell like this way.

```
collView.reloadData()
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
collView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
```

**Note :** Now there is no need to add code of color changing inside your `cellForIteamAtIndexPath` remove that code.

Comment: Well you may hit it :). So let's wait how Krutarh reacts.

Comment: Welcome mate, happy Coding :)

Comment: Note : one thing when you are dealing with dynamic data and returning row on basis of array, it is batter to check array is not empty before selecting first row.

Comment: if arr.count != 0 {
            CollVw.reloadData()
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
            CollVw.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)
            }

Comment: Yes just like that.

Comment: Can you please go through this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327611/how-to-delete-all-items-if-i-delete-one-of-them-in-tableview

Answer (score 1):

If you meant that you have **preselect your first cell**, then follow NDOC's answer.

Just a better explanation of your methods:

In `cellForItemAt` method:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0) { //for first cell in the collection
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //this is the color of the first row
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() //this is the color of the other rows
}
```

In `MyCollectionViewCell` Subclass:

```
//if any cell (first or other) is selected, it's bg color will be red
//if any cell will be deselected, it's bg color will be blue
didSet {
        contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.redColor(): UIColor.blueColor()
    }
```

It may confuse you, so change this line code to

```
contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.yellowColor(): UIColor.greenColor()
```

and you'll figure out, how it works.